# Relationship Model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

This question is about the Laravel style of doing things:

Everything in Laravel can be done in an elegant way.

I currently have a many to many relationship between `mongrels` and `breeds` through a table named `breed_mongrel` but this table also has a `certainty` value describing how certain the dog is that he's indeed a mix of that specific breed.

```
mongrel_id | breed_id | certainty|
----------------------------------
| 1        | 4        | 50       |
| 1        | 2        | 25       |
| 2        | 5        | 75       |
```

this means that mongrel#1 is 50% sure she's of breed#4 and 25% sure she's also a mix with breed#2. However mongrel#2 is a whooping 75% certain he is breed#5.

My question is what is the elegant way to add records to this table?
I could use something like this:

```
DB::table('breed_mongrel')->insert(
array('mongrel_id' => 3, 'breed_id' => 5, 'certainty' => 37));
```

But in Laravel I would normally do things more eloquently like:

```
$relation = new Relation;
$relation->breed_id = 1;
$relation->save();
```

But because it is a relationship and I can't follow the normal model named in singular camel caseform and DB table named in plural lower (snail) case I'm not sure what is Laravelly way to add entries to this database table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use attach. It also accepts a second parameter allowing extra values to be added to the pivot table.

```
$mongrel = Mongrel::find(1);
$breed   = Breed::find(4);
$mongrel->breeds()->attach($breed, array('certainty' => '50'));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the sort of thing I am looking for. I like to use this kind of syntactic sugar cause I think it keeps the code easier to read when you get back to it or when someone else needs to read it. :)